# CakePHP 3.6.14: Render view (.ctp) in a bootstrap modal

Tags: php, cakephp, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to display a view (add.ctp for example) in a [bootstrap modal](https://holt59.github.io/cakephp3-bootstrap-helpers/modal-helper/basics/)? And if so is it possible to render only the html in the add.ctp file without loading the default layout?

Because currently I am trying to build a custom form similar to the one in the add.ctp file in order to display it in the modal, and its really a pain trying to post and get the json objects in order to submit the form and populate the grids in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it`s possible.

Create add.ctp in Ajax folder, for example:

```
/Posts
  index.ctp
  /Ajax
  add.ctp
```

in Postings::add() set Ajax layout and with js get /posts/add and render modal.

Read:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts

**EDIT:**

in Controller

```
public function add()
{
   // your code here ...
   if ($this->getRequest()->is('ajax')) {
       // render "add" view in Ajax folder and use "ajax" Layout
       $this->render('Ajax/add', 'ajax')
   }
}
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#rendering-a-specific-template

EDIT 2 (jQuery part) example

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="<= $this->Url->build(/* ADD HERE YOUR PARAMS*/) 
 ?>" data-target="#myModel">Open Model</button>

$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){
        $($(this).data("target")+' .modal-body').load($(this).data("remote"));
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, probably it is what I am looking for. I am trying to find a working example beside the cakephp book, do you have any in mind?

Comment: Just create /Posts/Ajax/add.ctp, then in browser get /posts/ajax/add. Then in add method set ajax layout, and try again in browser. Now you have idea.

Comment: @Salines Can you provide code? I am straggling and I can't find a full working example...

Comment: @Salines Im straggling more with the modal, I have created my modal in view.ctp but on a button click I want to load the edit.ctp in this modal. I need help regarding the js code which will call the modal and load it with the edit.ctp instead of opening it in a new page

Comment: @dvn22, OK i will update, but not tested, just give you idea.